# Making app available in all countries

Tags: android, google-play, publishing

I have developed an application and just publishing it on playstore. In Country selection, I am selecting all the countries. I haven't localized my application, It is in single language (English). So is there any downside of selecting all countries in terms of rating and all if it is not localized or Selecting all countries is ok?

Comment: Its the same as a user changing their device language to non-english and them finding out your app doesn't support their language of choice.  Not a great user experience.

Answer (score 0):

The problem would be that if you hardcoded your `string.xml` in your app your language will not change for each country and will stay in English, perhaps your app description in the store will change according to any language.

You could use [Locale](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html) to get the user's language from their phone and change the app language by doing this, or just add the languages manually in `string.xml` , inside `res - values`.

PS: don't be worried about rating, the only downside is that people using the app and not understanding English.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting all countries is OK. It means that in those countries users will only see an English version. For a non-english speaking user it sucks as an experience, but they get a few hints ( like the store listing will show as auto-translated ).

Expect a lower rating in those countries. However, it will be good for English speaking users in those countries.